# Prevent position:absolute from taking content out of the flow of a vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue is illustrated in the first column of this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvc16uko/).

Basically, I want to make a first column in a table that stays fixed when scrolling horizontally, but not vertically. I found a solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/), but this only works when there isn't a vertical scrollbar. With that included, the first column leaves the flow of the containing div and the scroll bar doesn't apply to it.

How do I get around this? Is there a way to do this without `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`? I had the idea of hiding the portion of the first column that flows out of the scrollbar, but I'm not sure how this is implemented.